# How to get a live-steam video into the carousel at the top of the Google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search, googlebot, json-ld, google-search-api

I want whenever a live stream content is available on my website like a sports match then I want to Google to show a live stream preview in its result from the video tag.

[image]

What I think is I need to inject Google Structured Data (JSON+LD) in my video page but I cannot depend on or wait for google crawler/spider as the live steam can be scheduled within a short notice of a day or can be postponed anytime.

**Problems**

How to show live stream badge in google search?

How to notify google immediately about the live steam video or a change?

Comment: [Cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50147936/1591669)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, Google uses for such goals a socalled real time indexing API. You'll get more detailed info reading [this post](https://searchengineland.com/google-introduces-search-live-coverage-carousel-real-time-indexing-search-results-257928).

In short, you should:

- implement AMP,
- structured data,
- and push content to Google by Atom XML.

Comment: Do I have to implement AMP? is it possible to do it without AMP